# Limit size of the production archive

Tags: caching, sencha-touch-2

I use Sencha Cmd 3 and Sencha 2.1 to build my ST app in production mode and the cached app on the browser gets updated via deltas. For the deltas to work correctly, Sencha says that the archive folder that is generated and updated along the build must be kept intact. The size of this archive folder raises roughly by 0.5 MB every time I deploy new version.

Is there a way to keep the size of the archive folder within some limits while making sure that the deltas continue to be generated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have experience with delta's on Sencha, I'm guessing the reason is Sencha keeps a delta to each previous build.
For example, I you would have three builds (1.0, 1.2, 1.3), on your fourth build 3 delta's are created:

- 1.0 --> 1.4
- 1.2 --> 1.4
- 1.3 --> 1.4

If you have builds that are not deployed to users, you could take a look in the archive folder if you could remove the delta's that aren't needed.
Hope this helps!